# HTML5 Video (mp4) on Internet Explorer 11 has no fullscreen option

Tags: html, html5-video, internet-explorer-11, html5-fullscreen

I'm playing around with HTML5 videos on a webpage with the usual controls - play/pause, track, volume and fullscreen. These videos are of the mp4/ogg format. 80% of my user base uses Internet Explorer 11 (courtesy Google Analytics) and the remaining - Mozilla Firefox, Chrome and Safari. The problem is - all controls excepting the fullscreen control doesn't appear on IE11. Works like a charm on all other browsers.

caniuse[dot]com/#feat=fullscreen suggests that IE11 has native fullscreen support.

Here's an example:

The embedded video on [this](http://techslides.com/sample-webm-ogg-and-mp4-video-files-for-html5) page allows fullscreen with a button.

Using the same code with the 'controls' attribute on the  element doesn't show the fullscreen option on IE11.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jaisfiddles/f1apusx3/

```
<video controls> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg> 
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
  <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
</video>
```

What am I missing? I was under the impression that IE11 has msRequestFullscreen() api code enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seemed to have stumbled across the solution myself.

My `video` element was contained within an `iFrame`. In order to make the fullscreen option available, I had the specify

```
<iframe allowfullscreen="true">
```

With other major browsers like Mozilla Firefox, Chrome etc, this wasn't necessary.

Refer to Known Issues on http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

"IE 11 does not properly support fullscreen when opening from an iframe."

Answer (score 0):

I HAVE seen on some website that IE11 doesn't support Full Screen!!!
It won't support the full screen api until version 11.
Even IE10 has no fullscreen API!!
Because they are native controls;
 they don't use the full screen API.

Comment: As mentioned on the question, I'm using IE11! Please read again.

Answer (score 0):

let to open from chrome with creating a redirect.html as;

```
http://~~/redirect.html?redirectUrl=<your adress>
redirect.html>>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html lang="tr"> 

<head> 

<title>Please wait..Lütfen Bekleyiniz...</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function openURL() { 
debugger; 
var url = getParameterByName("redirectUrl"); 

if (!url) 
return; 

if (msieversion()) { 
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
shell.run("Chrome " + url); 
window.open('', '_self', ''); 
window.close(); 
} 
else { 
window.location.href = url; 
} 
} 

function msieversion() { 

var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; 
var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE "); 

if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number 
{ 
return true; 
} 

return false; 
} 

function getParameterByName(name, url) { 
debugger; 
if (!url) url = window.location.href; 
// name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&"); 
// var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"), 
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&"); 
var regex = new RegExp("[?]" + name + "(=([^]*)||$)"), 
results = regex.exec(url); 
if (!results) return null; 
if (!results[2]) return ''; 
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " ")); 
} 
</script> 
</head> 

<body onload="openURL()"> 
</body> 

</html>
```